# Python django load error

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django in django tutorial part3

but I have a problem

I updated my index view in polls/views.py to use the template

I loaded the page by pointing my browser at “/polls/”

but this is not working

I have a FieldError at /polls/

this is traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/polls/

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['polls.apps.PollsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/choco/python3/django/mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html, error at line 1
   Cannot resolve keyword 'pub_' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question_text
   1 :  {% if latest_question_list %} 
   2 :     <ul>
   3 :     {% for question in latest_question_list %}
   4 :         <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
   5 :     {% endfor %}
   6 :     </ul>
   7 : {% else %}
   8 :     <p>No polls are available.</p>
   9 : {% endif %}
   10 : 

Traceback:
```

this is view.py

```html
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

Comment: You need to show the code for your view.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late. I uploaded my view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `polls/views.py`

Check index function

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    output = ', '.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

> latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-**pub_date**')[:5]

maybe by mistake you have written `pub_` only or something like that.

Seems to be a typo.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late. I uploaded my view code
I do not know if there's a typo in my code

Comment: this proble has solved 
I do not know where the problem was.....thank u!

Comment: I don't know that because I just  Turned the server off and back on
Then it worked

Comment: Aha, maybe server would have not got auto-restarted with the latest code changes.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this issue !!